# Http error code response

Tags: json, rest, http, restful-architecture

What is the best practice to return some error codes like **400, 412, 402** etc. ?
Can I return some kind of JSON if I'm creating restfull api ? 
For example, if I send request *POST .../cars/1* and I get 402 then should or could server return to me some kind of JSON if i need data? and I do not want to increase traffic on server too much.

tl;dr:
Should/could restfull api return data when server send error code for example **4XX [without 404]**

Answer (score 1):

It should reply with that code [STATUS](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) so any client can understand it.

And then a good pratice is to check the [Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) sent by the client and reply a response encoded with any of the supported format. So for example the client has *application/javascript* It seems that it is expecting that format.

Comment: but it is good practice to send some kind of data like "user tokens" in response in "negative status" for example 402 ?

Comment: Probably It won't be helpful returning the user tokens. But other information regarding the error itself can be useful for debugging or understand the error. For example the Error 401 (Unauthorized) could be send together with a reason like 'Account blocked' or 'Password expired' just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

you make your response object and send status in that 
for example.
{
"status":400,
data:{
"error":"this is error response",
"isSuccess":true
}
}
and send response status in response